# Error: Objectives cannot be longer than 16 characters

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I make use of scoreboards to keep track of variables. However, this error popped up on the console when I tried reloading my datapack:

```
Failed to load function terraria:wands/rod_of_discord/use
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Whilst parsing command on line 5:
Objective names cannot be longer than 16 characters
```

```
Failed to load function terraria:load
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Whilst parsing command on line 3:
Objective names cannot be longer than 16 characters
```

This is my corresponding code:

```
# terraria:load
# Reset scoreboards
scoreboard objectives remove click
scoreboard objectives remove rod_cd

# Create scoreboards
scoreboard objectives add click minecraft.used:minecraft.carrot_on_a_stick
scoreboard objectives add rod_cd dummy

# Debug
execute as ShadeOfLight run say Terraria datapack startup finished.
```

```
# terraria:wands/rod_of_discord/use
# Effect
execute as @a[scores={click=1..,rod_cd=0},nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"carrot_on_a_stick",Count:1b,nbt:{Item:rod_of_discord}}}] at @a[scores={click=1..,rod_cd=0},nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"carrot_on_a_stick",nbt:{Item:rod_of_discord}}}] run spreadplayers ~ ~ 0 100 false @p

# Cooldown
execute as @a[scores={click=1..,rod_cd=0},nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"carrot_on_a_stick",Count:1b,nbt:{Item:rod_of_discord}}}] run scoreboard players set @p rod_cd 1000

# Reset scoreboard
execute as @a[scores={click=1..}] run scoreboard players set @p click 0
```

I used no objective names longer than 16 characters, at least to my knowledge. I tried commenting out everything in terraria:wands/rod_of_discord/use, but to no avail. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Which of them are commands on line 3 and 5? The compiler is telling you that the problem is there.

Comment: The commands have no error, since I tried commenting them out and it did not work. I also tried running the exact same commands in command blocks, and that worked. I suspect this might be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hindsight:

I have been testing with the wrong version of my datapack! I edited the one in my documents folder, while the old bugs persisted in the version in my datapacks folder. Sorry for wasting so much time!

Comment: If you have answered your own question you should mark it as the correct answer so it is clear that the issue is settled.